# Is $H_0$ reducible to $\overline H_0$?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, reductions

Be $H_0$ the special halting problem with
$$H_0 = \lbrace \langle M \rangle \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^* | \varepsilon \in L(M)\rbrace$$
and $\overline{H_0}$ being its complement.
Is $H_0$ reducible to $\overline{H_0}$? 
$$H_0 \leq \overline{H_0}$$

I guess that this is not possible as $\overline H_0$ is not semi-decidable, but I am not sure how to approach such questions in general and how I would really prove it in this case in particular.
Are there any properties of problems that forbid the reduction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such reduction does not exist.

If $H_0 \le \overline{H_0}$ then you can simply decide $H_0$:

given input $\left<M\right>$ calculate the reduction $f(\left<M\right>)$ and Simultaneously run $\left<M\right>$ and $f(\left<M\right>)$ with empty input. 
If $\left<M\right>$ halts return the same answer, If $f(\left<M\right>)$ halts 
flip the answer and halt.

We have $\epsilon\in L\left(\left<M\right>\right) \iff \epsilon\notin L\left(f\left(\left<M\right>\right)\right)$ hence one of the machines has to halt and our newly constructed machine for deciding $H_0$ always halts.